# Can I put tooltips in a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, tooltip

This doesn't work:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to do this? My real goal is to identify the second links in the graph below, which shows the results of a webcrawl (using [this](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/graph-and-network-modeling/structure-of-the-web.html) code). I'm open to another approach.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I had a similar question a long time ago - David Carraher's answer may be useful for you. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742126/edgelabels-in-a-web-structure-visualization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Graph[{1, 2, Tooltip[3, "Label"]},
     {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

You can also explicitly label using `VertexLabels` and use `Tooltip` as the positioning:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5}, 
    VertexLabels -> {5 -> Placed["five", Tooltip]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I accept both answers?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe You can't... You can upvote both if you like them and they answered your question, but you can accept only one answer. Typically I suggest that people accept the one that they found the most useful or the one they ended up using in their code or the clearest one. However, different people have widely different metrics to break ties, ranging from tossing a coin to looking at the time stamps or accepting the answer from the lower rep user (I realize I lose out on the last two). Feel free to choose as you wish :)